# What is causing this display quirk on [Delphi] questions?

Tags: support, ignored-tags

Recently, very occasionally (maybe once a week), if I browse Stack Overflow questions for [delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi), a question will be displayed with the text almost white, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61780858/2663863) currently is, as of 14 May 2020, 10:32 GMT.  There is no apparent reason for this.

In case it helps see what I mean, the "Reading DateTime ..." in the screenshot below has this quirk.:

[image: Screenshot of Delphi questions on SO]

The way this particular question is being displayed has persisted overnight, so it doesn't seem to be a transient problem.

Fwiw I'm using FF 76.0.1 on Win10 64-bit.

What attribute/characteristic of the question is causing this and is it a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can just see from the extreme right of your screenshot that database is in your list of ignored tags but delphi is in your list of watched tags.

That question has both tags so it's listed because it's in your watched tags list but less prominently because it also has another tag you wanted to ignore. There's more information on [the Stack Exchange Meta about watching and ignoring tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-watched-tags-and-ignored-tags-do)

Comment: Thanks, that must be the reason.  As my q got d/voted within seconds of being posted,  I'm not sure whether I should delete it or leave it as a reminder to other infrequent users of the 'ignore tags' facility.